# Python SimpleHTTPServer serving wrong index.html?

Tags: python, html, web

I have a simple script for viewing the webpage I am working on.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
PORT = 8000 
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I've copied this script to a few directories with different index.html pages I am working on. I killed the server serving index_A (in its own directory, Development/A). However when I try to run the script in Development/B (which should serve index_B) it is still serving index_A.

Edit: When I change the port I am using, it serves the correct index. Still not sure why the old index shows up in the old port, even when I kill the process.

Comment: Are you really killing the original (`A`) server process? Are you sure you've switched directories before running the `B` server? Have you confirmed--I mean really looked with fresh eyes to make sure--the content is where you think it is? Sorry to be blunt, but pilot error is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I used filip's solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac to kill the process, would that not be sufficient? I am sure about running it in different directories.

Comment: There are a lot of solutions there, but I assume you mean something like `kill -9 \`lsof -i :8000 | egrep -v PID | awk '{print $2}'\``, which should be reliable.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same problem and it was very distressing and stubborn. Tried all the suggestions here and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521912/local-server-giving-wrong-files-is-it-possible-im-running-2-python-servers/22522021#22522021/) with commands `freeport`, `netstat`, `ps`, `lsof` and `kill`. Few hours later found that it was something more elementary. Even after several restarts the same `index.html` was still being served at `0.0.0.0:8000`. But tried the other browsers and it was only happening in Chrome! so cleared the cache and it went away.